# Problema con la página de confirmación en ASP.NET MVC: Valor Value llega como 0

Tags: asp.net, payu

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en **ASP.NET MVC** y estoy enfrentando un problema inusual con mi página de confirmación. Estoy integrando la pasarela de pago de **PayU** y cuando recibo la confirmación de la transacción, el campo Value siempre llega con el valor 0, a pesar de que, según mis registros y lo que puedo ver en las herramientas de diagnóstico, debería recibir un valor diferente.

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

He asegurado que el modelo **PayUConfirmation** esté correctamente mapeado con todos los campos.

He intentado leer el cuerpo de la solicitud directamente desde `Request.InputStream` para verificar si el problema es con la vinculación del modelo, pero el valor sigue siendo 0.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Confirmation(PayUConfirmation model)
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)); 

     string apiKey = "xxXXxxXXxxXXxxXXXxxxXXXxxxXX";
     string generatedSignature = CreateSignature(apiKey, 
    model.Merchant_id, model.Reference_sale, model.Value, 
    model.Currency, model.State_pol);

     if (generatedSignature.Equals(model.Sign, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         // La firma es válida
        // GuardarBase(model);  // Guardar en la base de datos
        // EnviarEmail(model);  // Enviar correo con el resumen de la compra y el código QR
     }
     else
     {
         // La firma no es válida. 
     }

     return  new EmptyResult();
```

Pero, sorprendentemente, cuando deserializo este JSON a mi modelo PayUConfirmation, el campo Value es 0.
Pregunta:
¿Alguien ha enfrentado un problema similar o tiene alguna idea de qué podría estar causando este comportamiento? Cualquier sugerencia o recomendación sería de gran ayuda.

Modelo

```
public class PayUConfirmation
 {
     public int Merchant_id { get; set; }
    
     public string State_pol { get; set; }
     public decimal Risk { get; set; }
     public string Response_code_pol { get; set; }
     public string Reference_sale { get; set; }
     public string Reference_pol { get; set; }
     public string Sign { get; set; }
     public string Extra1 { get; set; }
     public string Extra2 { get; set; }
     public int Payment_method { get; set; }
     public int Payment_method_type { get; set; }
     public int Installments_number { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("value")]
     public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Incluye la vista por favor, me late que el valor es 0 porque el nombre no hace match con el modelo.

Comment: es que en payu hay respuesta y confirmación con la respuesta no tengo ningún problema los valores llegan de forma correcta. como la confirmación llega directamente al controlador no tengo ninguna vista  y value es el único que llega 0 y no necesito para realizar la validadcion de la firma.